# numpy array to Colored table or image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following numpy array :

```
 ([[    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    27,   541,  1296, 10000],
   [    0,     0,     0,     0,     1,    44,   355,  1998,  3272, 10000],
   [    0,     0,     0,     2,    18,   209,  1069,  3239,  4670, 10000],
   [    0,     0,     0,    10,    96,   486,  1522,  3954,  5379, 10000],
   [    0,     0,     2,    28,   216,   748,  2127,  4769,  6011, 10000],
   [    0,     0,    18,    82,   379,  1200,  2867,  5395,  6528, 10000],
   [    0,     3,    39,   147,   599,  1489,  3237,  5740,  6909, 10000],
   [    0,     6,    48,   246,   759,  1777,  3610,  6034,  7144, 10000],
   [    0,    12,    90,   324,  1009,  2072,  3980,  6365,  7466, 10000],
   [    1,    12,   119,   438,  1103,  2337,  4215,  6594,  7568, 10000]])
```

what i want to is to create grey-colored table/image where bigger number is darker color.
In addition I want to set the x&y axis to defined values.

```
x-axis : [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
y-axis : [500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4200, 4500]
```

I've been playing with imshow, with unsatisfactory results so far.

```
 fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
 ax1.imshow(np.flipud(x), cmap='Greys', interpolation='nearest', extent=[100,1001,500,4501])
 ax1.set_xticklabels(xaxis)
 ax1.set_yticklabels(yaxis)
 ax1.grid()
 fig.show()
```

First the image should be square, second interpolation smears the exactness of the range (grid is in the middle of cell not the edge).

[image]

Comment: Could you please say why it doesn't work?

Comment: I always look in the Matplotlib Gallery (examples) - [pylab_examples example code: equal_aspect_ratio.py](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/equal_aspect_ratio.html#pylab-examples-example-code-equal-aspect-ratio-py)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this be a satisfactory result?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")
cmap = sns.color_palette("Greys", 8)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = sns.heatmap(x, cmap=cmap, vmax=10000, vmin=0,
                 square=True, linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5},
                 xticklabels=[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000], 
                 yticklabels=[4500, 4200, 4000, 3500, 3000, 2500, 2000, 1500, 1000, 500])
```

[image]

Comment: is there any chance I can also put the numbers in the cells ??

Comment: @user1019129 Simply pass arguments `annot=True, fmt='d'` to the heatmap function